# How to fix tfoot with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fix the tfoot of my table to the bottom of the table wrapper with jquery, the reason being that it has to work in IE11 and position: fixed doesn't work because of the layout of the web.

I already fixed the thead, but i cannot get it to work on the tfoot.

This is my html

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <th></th>
         <td></td>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
```

This is some css

```
.table-wrapper {
   max-height: 450px;
   height: auto;
   overflow-y: auto !important;
   overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

This is how i fixed the thead with jquery

```
var $tableWrapper = $(".table-wrapper");
var $th = $tableWrapper.find("thead th");

$tableWrapper.on("scroll", function() {
   $th.css("transform", "translateY("+ this.scrollTop +"px)");
});
```

I'm trying to fix it without changing the layout and css, only with jquery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's up with the weird doubled single quotes in your jQuery?

Comment: because its inside sql, i'll change it now